# Display only some data from the api

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, frontend

Recovering data from api Hello everyone, I need some help about displaying data from an api

I have a problem to display the data on my front-end as you can see I use an api that allows me to retrieve data("name", "address", "price") about 100 cryptos. All these data appear in the console.log( res.data) and the console.log(res.data[1].price) allows me to display only one data of the second cryptos of the list which is its price. I would like to be able to do exactly the same thing on the front-end in the sense that I want to use this api to retrieve the data of the 100 cryptos but I want to be able to display the data one by one on the front-end which I can't. In return you can see the code that allows me to display the price of the 100 cryptos at once but this is not what I want to do I would like to be able to display for example only the price of the third crypto of the list on the front-end

Thanks in advance for your answer

The script :

```
function App(){
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const fetchData = () => {
  axios
  .get('http://localhost:4500/sushiswap')
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data)
    console.log(res.data[1].price)
    setData(res.data)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
}, [])

return(
  <Fragment>
    <ul>
      {data.map(item =>(
        <li key={item.name}>
          <p>{item.price.slice(0, 8)}</p>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </Fragment>
)
```

Out for first console.log : (100) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

0: adress: "0x397ff1542f962076d0bfe58ea045ffa2d347aca0" name: "USDC/ETHView chart" price: "$1.0101$1.01010.000928 ETH0.000928 ETH" [[Prototype]]: Object

There are 100 of these

out for second console.log : $1,084.77$1,08545.38 ALCX45.38 ALCX

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly are you trying to achieve? if you want to display only the third item on the list you should use {data[2].price}

Comment: Is it a problem that `address` seems to be misspelled `adress` in your log?

Comment: @talm0r Indeed when I replace in the <Fragment> section {item.price.slice(0, 8)} with {data[1].price} it shows me on the front end the price of the second crypto that's what I wanted. But it shows me the price 100 times on the page do you know where I have to see to change this? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Wyck No it's me when I did the api I made a mistake by forgetting a d a address

Comment: Because you are iterating the array when you are doing data.map, you should remove data.map and only put {data[1].price}

Comment: @talm0r In the end there is always a small problem when I use map it gives me the same price 100 times and when I do not use map as you told me it does not show the same price 100 times and it appears in the right visual form. So it's good but the problem that arises is that when I just launched the app and I make for the first time the request to the api and I do not use map, the terminal says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'price')" I think that the code below return should be executed only after the data from the api is loaded. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: You can use {data[1] && data[1].price}